# Azure Logic App trigger fires only once then never fires again

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app set up to trigger when a new email appears with a specific label. This event kicked of once as expected when I added a label to the email. Now however, the trigger no longer kicks off when the label is added

[image]

after the intial test of adding the label in which the trigger kicked off, the trigger no longer kicks off when the label is added to the email. Should this be happening this way, or am I missing something to properly kick off this trigger every time the label is added to the email

Answer (score 0):

As the picture shown, you `Label` specify to `LogicApp`, try to find out that does the email you send later meets the rule you set for `LogicApp`.

Also, you can set one minute to check for the items so that the logic app will quick and accurate help you check the email.

You can refer to the snapshot as below:

[image]